# How do you correctly use objects with in React Components (namely, Form.Control)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, forms, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I'm working on a project, and so far my research tells me this code should be printing out the text I need, but it keeps printing "object [Object]" and I'm not entirely sure why. [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmmCA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2S9N.png)

I use the map function to iterate over an array of objects. On every click of "Test 'appendLog'", it uses array spread syntax to add the new item when using 'setLogs', and the 'Form.Control' component takes in 'logs' as a value, then uses 'map' function to iterate over all the logs and print them into the 'textarea' (i.e., Form.Control component) to do this but it only prints 'object [Object]' every time. I could pass in the 'logs' via *JSON.strigify(logs)* but then I'd have to do extra work to parse and make it more readable. I wanted to just use the *logs* and make it simpler for maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logs.map before Form.Control and use the same in value.

```
{logs.map((log) => (
  <Form.Control
    readOnly
    as={"textarea"}
    rows={"20"}
    value={`Msg: ${log.logtext} by ${log.initials}`}
  >
    <p key={log.id}>
      Msg: ${log.logtext} by {log.initials}
    </p>
  </Form.Control>
))}
```

[image]

Comment: This will create a whole new textarea with the new message instead of using it in the same textarea. This unfortunately doesn't do what's intended.